# Celery cannot retrieve active tasks on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I am trying to deploy an app on Heroku and I am using Celery and Redis to manage background tasks. I currently have a background task that collects data via FTP and puts it in the database. I also have a loading page that periodically refreshes until the task completes. However, I cannot retrieve the list of active tasks (inspect from celery.task.control returns None). This problem only occurs on Heroku, but everything works on my personal machine.

Earlier, this was also occuring on my machine, but I fixed this by downgrading Kombu to 4.5.0. However, changing requirements.txt did not make a difference on Heroku. I also tried checking the value of os.environ['REDIS_URL'], and looks correct.

relevant code from settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
    }
}


CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'genome.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
app = Celery('genome_app')

app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
                CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

requirements.txt

```
django<=2.2.2
gunicorn<=19.6.0
requests>=2.22.0
celery==4.3.0
kombu==4.5.0
redis>=3.2.1
django-redis-cache>=2.0.0
django-celery-beat>=1.5.0
django-celery-results>=1.1.2
```

(in the app's views.py)

```
from celery.task.control import inspect

...

i = inspect() 
active_tasks = list(i.active().values())[0]
```

In Heroku's logs, I see the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I cannot see how possibly can the last piece of code (that inspects) work... Are you sure it works (unmodified) on your workstation?

Comment: Sorry, I am missing a newline. Let me fix that.

Comment: @ErolB Any updates on how you solved this issue?